# How to set the allowed protocol for a node.js HTTPS server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

I have built a HTTPS server using the default `https` module and `express`.

However, I can't find anywhere how to tell it to only use the latest version of TLS, nor any information on which version of SSL/TLS was supported by the default server.

I did found some express middlware promising to [enforce SSL](https://github.com/battlejj/express-force-ssl), but SSL is obsolete since 2015, and there is still no information on which version is enforced.

How can I define which version of TLS to use for my app? Or at least how to find out which version is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) documentation. They refer to your OpenSSL version, for example [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html).

So if you set `secureProtocol` in the options, you can choose the protocol.

Comment: This seems to be for the request, I want to set the authorized protocol server side (as if, refuse any request asking for SSL, even if OpenSSL from my side could support it)

Comment: I think you can use the same options here: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener.